# Unable to Log In to Domain Computers with Spoiled Domain Controller

Tags: networking, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-10

The domain controller in our domain network is completely down and we don't plan to repair it. We couldn't log in to the computers because of that.

[image]

Worst case, we even forgot the local admin password. We are trying to use the bootable USB to reset the local admin password but the BIOS requests for an admin password which we don't know.

[image]

We are really stuck now and don't what to do. We contacted Dell but they said there is nothing they can do to help. Hope some experts here may suggest us anything if that works.

Thanks a lot. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect the computers from the physical network. If the domain user credentials have been cached on the computers this will allow the user to log in with those cached credentials. You can then take whatever steps are needed to reconfigure the computers.

Additionally, contact Dell support again and ask them if there is a way to disable or override the BIOS password.

Comment: For a 2012-era consumer AIO desktop? I don't think he's getting a way to disable the BIOS password. And what on earth is a domain controller doing on one of those anyway?

Comment: I got the impression that was a picture of a client, not the DC.

Comment: Hi, joeqwerty. Thanks for your reply. We did try to disconnect the ethernet cable and WiFi. It still doesn't allow us to log in. It initially allowed us to log in just once with the cached account and later it just prompts us that message in the screenshot. You're right, that's the client PC.